# Cannot install django-dash

Tags: python, django

I am trying to install django-dash on my Ubuntu 14.04.
However I am getting the following error:

```
Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_dash-0.4.13.dist-info'
```

I am using this command to install djangoi-dash:

```
pip install django-dash
```

What is the solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried running  `sudo pip install django-dash`?

Comment: thanks... it got installed using sudo

Answer (score 0):

As Juuso already answered in a comment above, you need to run `pip` with `sudo` to be able to install a python package globally.

```
sudo pip install django-dash
```

Instead of installing django and third-party packages globally as the root user, I would recommend to use isolated Python environments for django developement/deployment. Have a look at [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) and [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to create and use isolated Python environments.